# How to get the exit status of multiple parallel background processes in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, exit

In Bash, I want to call a command multiple times in parallel, while capturing all the processes exit codes.

I know how to start and wait for them, but wait will only give me the exit code of the last process exiting. I also need the exit code of the shorter lived processes.

Unfortunately I don't have bash 4.3, so `wait -n` is not an option, nor is gnu parallel as suggested in [#3004811](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

[#16032001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032001/how-can-i-check-the-exit-status-of-multiple-processes-in-background-in-loop) pretty much asks the same question but no solution was offered there either.

The only way I can currently think of is writing a helper script that stores the exit codes in a file, but this doesn't sound like a clean solution.

Comment: This answer could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048390/5291015

Comment: in `C` you can do this. But you should notice that you have to wait for all processes to be terminated one-by-one. When a process exits, **wait** family clean up them one by one. **exit status of multiple parallel processes does not make sense**

Comment: I know I can do this in C, but I have very limited ressources on that server, and generally would not like to mess with the executables there (It's a Xen server). Maybe i used incurrect wording, but i want to start, say 10 backup processes in parallel, and need to check if each of them succeeded.

Comment: I understood what you said. I want to say that there is no magic things to get  the return value of each process. [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409877/cleaning-up-children-processes-asynchronously/46174954#46174954). It does not matter; you are using `bash` or `c` any others. you have to wait for any background process you have. and [see this one about wait in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish)

Comment: I'm not an experienced Unix c programmer, but I know in principle how fork(), wait, SIGCHILD and zombie processes play together. I was hoping there would be a way to tell bash: "Wait for the next of the background processes to exit and give their exit code" (maybe what wait -n does). Or alternatively store the exit code into some variable. The real trouble is, that bash does not keep zombies, but immediately reaps them. So I have to run wait while the sub-process exits or I will miss the exit code...

Comment: Found my mistake, thanks for the hepling pointers.

Comment: `GNU Parallel is not an option`. Can you elaborate on that after reading http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is in [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0/356154#356154)

I was unaware that though the child is immediately reaped by bash, the builtin wait can still access the exit code for the pid.

```
#!/bin/bash

FAIL=0
PIDS=""

echo "starting"

sleep 5 &
PIDS="$PIDS $!"

sleep 3 &
PIDS="$PIDS $!"

/bin/false &
PIDS="$PIDS $!"

sleep 3 &
PIDS="$PIDS $!"

for job in $PIDS
do
    wait $job || let "FAIL+=1"
    echo $job $FAIL
done

echo $FAIL

if [ "$FAIL" == "0" ];
then
    echo "YAY!"
else
    echo "FAIL! ($FAIL)"
fi
```

correctly gives

```
starting
14772 0
14773 0
14774 1
14775 1
1
FAIL! (1)
```

Only the third process (/bin/false) fails, indicated by the switch from 0 to one in the third line.

Comment: When you want to store a list of items, consider using an array, not a string. This code is fragile -- as soon as `IFS` gets changed to a different value, `$PIDS` will no longer evaluated to your intended list.

Comment: (Also, avoid `==` in `[ ]` -- it's not guaranteed by the POSIX standard for `test` to work; the only mandated string comparison operator is `=`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: (Also, keep in mind that all-caps variable names are used by variables with the OS or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use, and thus guaranteed not to conflict; see relevant standard @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph)