# find pattern in multiple files and perform some action on them

Tags: awk, grep

I have 2 files - file1.txt and file2.txt.
I want to set a condition such that, a command is run on both files only if a pattern "xyz" is present in both files. Even if one file fails to have that pattern, the command shouldn't run. Also , I need to have both files being passed to the grep or awk command at the same time as I am using this code inside another workflow language.
I wrote some code with grep, but this code performs the action even if the pattern is present in one of the files, which is not what I want . Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

```
if grep "xyz" file1.txt file2.txt; then
     my_command file1.txt file2.txt 
else 
     echo " command cannot be run on these files"
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: [How to get the exit status of multiple parallel background processes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46193327/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk -v s='xyz' 'FNR == NR {
   if ($0 ~ s) {
      ++p
      nextfile
   }
   next
}
FNR == 1 {
   if (!p) exit 1
}
{
   if ($0 ~ s) {
      ++p
      exit
   }
}
END {
   exit p < 2
}' file1 file2
```

This will exit with `0` if given string is found in **both the files** otherwise it will exit with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Salvaging code from a deleted answer by [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus):

```
if grep -q "xyz" file1.txt && grep -q "xyz" file2.txt; then
  echo "xyz was found in both files"
else
  echo "xyz was found in one or no file"
fi
```

If you need to run a single command, save this as a script, and run that script in your condition.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
grep -q "xyz" "$1" && grep -q "xyz" "$2"
```

If you save this in your `PATH` and call it `grepboth` (don't forget to `chmod a+x grepboth` when you save it) your condition can now be written

```
grepboth file1.txt file2.txt
```

Or perhaps `grepall` to accept a search expression and a list of files;

```
#!/bin/sh
what=$1
shift
for file; do
    grep -q "$what" "$file" || exit
done
```

This could be used as

```
grepall "xyz" file1.txt file2.txt
```